# How to make a character's health persist in a sort of RPG I am coding

Tags: python

I am trying to make a basic fight sequence for an RPG just to figure out how things should work in it.
here is the code I have written so far:

```
`import random

Situ = input("1 to attack, 2 to guard")
Inpu = int(Situ)
playing = True

Enemy_Damage = [25, 50]
Enemy_Guard = 0.5
Character_Damage = [10, 20]
Character_Guard = 0.5

while playing:
    
    Character = None
    Enemy = None
    
    Character_Health = 100
    Enemy_Health = 75
    
    attack = [f"You Attacked The Enemy! Enemy Health: {Enemy_Health - random.choice(Character_Damage)}", f"You Attacked The Enemy! The Enemy succesfully guarded! Enemy Health: {Enemy_Health - random.choice(Character_Damage) * Enemy_Guard}"]
    
    guard = [f"The Enemy Attacked! You successfully guarded! Your Health: {Character_Health - random.choice(Enemy_Damage) * Character_Guard}", f"The Enemy Attacked! You failed to guard. Your Health: {Character_Health - random.choice(Enemy_Damage)}"]
    
    if Inpu == 1:
        print(random.choice(attack))
    
    elif Inpu == 2:
        print(random.choice(guard))
        
    PSit = input("1 to attack again, 2 to guard again")
    PInp = int(PSit)
        
    if Enemy_Health < Enemy_Health:
        Situ = input("1 to attack again, 2 to guard again")
        
    if Character_Health == 0:
        playing = False
        print("You Have Died!")
        
    if Enemy_Health == 0:
        playing = False
        print("You Attacked The Enemy! Enemy Health: 0")
        print("You Won The Fight!")`
```

it works fine for what I am trying to do as of now, except that as I continue to fight the enemy or the enemy fights me, the health that we have is based on the number I originally specify (Character_Health = 100, Enemy_Health = 100) so I can keep fighting and never win and never lose since it always goes back to the max health. How would I make it so that the health of me and the enemy changes until I restart the program?

I have not tried much to solve this because I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Shift `Character_Health = 100` and `Enemy_Health = 75` to outside of the while loop. If it is within the loop, every time the loop restarts it will set the health to `100` and `75` again.

As a side note, it's good practice to follow style conventions such as [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) to make your code more readable and easily understandable for you and others.

Comment: I put the character and enemy health outside of the while loop but I still have the same problem, it looks like this:
You Attacked The Enemy! Enemy Health: 55
1 to attack again, 2 to guard again
1
You Attacked The Enemy! Enemy Health: 55
1 to attack again, 2 to guard again
1
You Attacked The Enemy! The Enemy succesfully guarded! Enemy Health: 70.0

The health still resets every time I prompted to attack or guard

Comment: You also need to actually update the health variables. Currently your strings of `attack` and `guard` are doing a calculation to print but not updating the actual values. So, set the `random.choice()` outside of the `attack` and `guard` string, change it so you generate a random int to pick whether or not the `attack` or `guard` was successful, and update the relevant values before printing.